# How to bind to solution configuration from XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I am building my application using the Release configuration, I want to set a property to `true`, but otherwise I want to set it to `false`. I have something as follows in mind:

```
<Window Topmost="{Binding IsReleaseBuild}">
```

Normally I would just use preprocessor directives `#if` and `#endif` to check for the `DEBUG` constant, but this isn't possible in XAML.

**What is the best way to handle this?**

[Most likely](http://ardalis.com/determine-whether-an-assembly-was-compiled-in-debug-mode) I can create a value to which I can bind in my data context. However, I'd prefer to create a reusable solution.

I could also just use the preprocessor directives in the code behind file, but I was wondering whether there was a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do something like this; based on the solution in the link you posted.

```
public bool IsReleaseBuild
{
    get { return MyStaticClass.IsAssemblyDebugBuild(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); }
}
```

If you are using `MVVM` you could simply put the `Property` in your `BaseClass` and allow it to be used by all `View/ViewModels`.

It could look something like this.

```
public class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public Boolean IsReleaseBuild
    {
        get
        {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

I do something similar to figure out if my application is currently in the `Visual Studio Design Mode`:

```
public class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private static Nullable<Boolean> _isInDesignMode;

    public Boolean IsInDesignMode
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_isInDesignMode.HasValue)
            {
                DependencyProperty property = DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty;

                _isInDesignMode
                    = (bool)DependencyPropertyDescriptor
                                    .FromProperty(property, typeof(FrameworkElement))
                                    .Metadata.DefaultValue;
            }

            return _isInDesignMode.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about an attached property?

```
public sealed class Solution
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReleaseBuildProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsReleaseBuild",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(Solution),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
#if DEBUG
            false
#else
            true
#endif
           ));

    public static bool GetIsReleaseBuild(DependencyObject source)
    {
        return (bool)source.GetValue(IsReleaseBuildProperty);
    }
}
```

And in your XAML:

```
<Window Topmost="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} Path=util:Solution.IsReleaseBuild}" />
```